# How to run scripts in django context from pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

How to run an arbitrary script in the django context while using pycharm?

Running an arbirtary script in the django context makes it easy to develop background tasks or do ad-hoc queries. The standard answer is to add the script to custom commands, however, I'm not used to that workflow and it seems an unnecessary step if you don't intend it to be exposed like this.

This is a question-and-answer post since I can't find this technique anywhere in StackOverflow and I thought it would help. I wanted an answer in my third hour of learning Django.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started with django. There may be better ways but I'm developing some tasks which will eventually be sent to celery and while developing them I find it convenient to quickly run them in the django context. I use pycharm

To do this:

set up a standard python run environment and make the script the script you want to execute. 
add an environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and set it to the python import path for your settings.py. Eg if you settings.py is in a directory called myapp:
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myapp.settings

make the working directory your project root 
leave the  "Add content roots" & "Add source roots" checkboxes ticked.

In the script, add these two lines at the top:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and now you can use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

and you're off and running.

or run tests or whatever.

It's easy then to run a script which needs Django context:

```
 PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings python dir1/dir2/myscript.py
```

Run that from the normal django root directory.

Credit to: Stavros Korokithakis https://www.stavros.io/ from this post: https://www.stavros.io/posts/standalone-django-scripts-definitive-guide/